# How to create immediate Notification System in website

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, notifications, social-networking

I am implementing a small social networking website, and I am trying to implement notifications.

Notifications have the following requirements

1. All users will receive notifications whenever users they follow do
   certain events (like a post, create a post,leave a comment, etc...
2. When a set of notifications for a user is unread, just like on facebook, the user will
   continue to see a read notification icon on their navbar.

Problem : I am taking an example to describe my problem for better understanding for everyone.

Suppose there are two users **A** and **B**. A & B are friends and A post something, suddenly B like the post of A then A should have to receive the notification immediately.

1. So how can i achieve this immediately receiving  of notification process?
2. Should i send a call to server on each millisecond to check whether there is any unread notification is available for A user ? In this case thousand millions of call creating for multiple user. It is feasible solution ? 
   (I think it create unnecessary load on my website. As i think facebook and stackoverflow do not use this way).

Provide me a suitable solution just like fb and other webiste using.

Technology Using in my project: Java and MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript (client side) along with Java - MySql (Server side), and more specifically [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You will need some time to understand the concept and the usage but it does exactly what you want.

To give more details, what you need is to create a partial view where the notifications will appear, and update this partial view async (with AJAX).

Comment: Sir, my problem is if i hit the server on each millisecond for single user to check unread notification is available or not? In this case thousand millions of call creating for multiple user ? It is feasible solution ??

Comment: @Kushal async concept means that when a new notification is available, display it. What you describe is a kind of <<while (1)>> technique, which of course is not feasible. But Ajax is out there, doing what you describe for many years. So as user3508453 said, don't reinvent the wheel, and accomplish this with the mainstream technique. Besides, Ajax is used on some really big (in the name of traffic - users) websites.

Answer (score 0):

Dont reinvent the wheel.
Use ajax call to server at each interval and check your server and update nav acc.

Answer (score 0):

1.So how can i achieve this immediately receiving of notification process?

2) Should i send a call to server on each millisecond to check whether there is any unread notification is available for A user ?

Your above both questions answers solve through [GWTEventService](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) implementation.
Through it you can write code that will avoid client to server round trip.

> GWTEventService is an event-based client-server communication framework. It uses GWT-RPC and the Comet / server-push technique. The client side offers a high-level API with opportunities to register listeners to the server like to a GUI component. Events can be added to a context/domain on the server side and the listeners on the client side get informed about the incoming events. The server side is completely independent of the client implementation and is highly configurable. Domains can be defined to decide which events are important for the different contexts.

Refer link: https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/

Comment: If you are talking about GWT RPC mechanism. I am already using it, so it is feasible to create thousand million of call to server for multiple users ?

Comment: no, it's not about rpc mechanism. it's not call from client to server. through it, write server side logic. whatever you write logic in server impl. it will execute according specific time. and broadcast message from server to client. (Remember: not client to server call, it is server to client call as given event like timer or any other condition whatever you give)

Comment: You are try to say that i create a timer on server impl side to check notification is available or not. If it is available then return to client. But it is really possible to create reverse call from server to client. As i know without creating a request from client to server, server would not able to respond. I am correct ?

Comment: it is server push technique. read why server push/comet programing? no need to create timer at server. server would respond to client with help of such technique. just Google it. try to implement it. if you stuck then ask..

Comment: Thanks for guide me, I try to learn server push/coment programming.